# What is the English name of 'Santol'?

Tags: translation

**Santol** is a Filipino term/name of a fruit. Others call it as a lolly fruit and cotton fruit. I wonder what's the correct name of it in English.

Comment: my friend, chief cook called it "wild mangosteen."

Answer (score 1):

See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandoricum_koetjape). A simple Google search for "santol" finds this page.

According to Wikipedia the local name in Nigeria is "udara". It has been introduced to India, but the article does not mention any local name used there. This fruit is not well known in America or Britain. Scientists will simply use the scientific name *Sandoricum koetjape*.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It's really hard to use the scientific name when talking to ordinary people.